# MVC - How to include a model inside _Layout for Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've seen how to use Partial Views from within a View and I understand how a model is passed from the View to a Partial View. What I don't grasp is how to include a Partial View inside of _Layout.cshtml so that I can pass it to the Partial View - or, how the Partial View itself can call a Controller Action to create a Model for use.

Specifically, I want to include a Partial View within _Layout.cshtml to display in the header of every page. The Partial View will display a custom setting in the User Profile. I can't think of any way to obtain the Model without making a Controller Action call - but how is this done in/for a Partial View from within _Layout.cshtml?

Is my only option of accessing a Controller Action to build my Partial View's required Model to use a jQuery call? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The answer is by calling `@Html.Action()`.**

It sounds like you're on the right track.

The key is to try to **not** pass multiple models around, make models complicated, or use the ViewBag needlessly.

Instead, any time you want information on every page, call an action from your _Layout.

For example, you might have a controller called `PartialsController` or `SharedController`.

```
public class PartialsController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult UserProfilePartial()
    {
        UserProfileModel model = new UserProfileModel();

        return PartialView("_UserProfile", model);
    }
}
```

The [`ChildActionOnlyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) means that users cannot access the action directly. Only your code can call the action. You can also **apply the attribute to the controller** so that it affects all actions automatically.

Now call the action from your view (_Layout).

```
@Html.Action("UserProfilePartial", "Partials")
```

Comment: Rowan and Tieson, I was using pretty much the same approach that Rowan provided (Thank you for the detail) and it works - so long as I am not posting the form. For example, it works when the Login page is displayed, but when I click the Submit button to login my PartialView is not being found. The return on the [HttpPost] of the PartialView is `return PartialView();`. You are showing the GET, how do I return from the POST Controller Action?

Comment: The same `return PartialView("_UserProfile", model);` seems to work in the POST.

Comment: It's difficult to answer without knowing what it is you're attempting to do. You might have to post another question, stating the HttpPost requirements and maybe with screenshots/drawings to demonstrate what you're doing.